# Highstock v3.0 how to disable tooltip timeout/delay

Tags: highcharts

In Highstock version 3.0 the tooltip has a delay/timeout before it hides.

Is there a way to disable/reduce this delay/timeout?

I'm not able to find the API docs for the latest version @ http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#tooltip

I hope there is an undocumented way of achieving this.

Comment: how about tooltip: { animation: false, enabled: false }?

Comment: @TomFobear I want the animation and the tooltip to be displayed. Just wanted to reduce/disable the delay in hiding the tooltip.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Highcharts 3.0 set `hideDelay` in tooltip options, see: http://jsfiddle.net/3aUuS/

We will update docs soon.

Comment: Is there a JavaScript way of forcefully hiding the tooltip, whatever the hideDelay the user might have specified?
FWIW, This is for a custom plugin.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking for. How to disable tooltip? Look comment under your question. How to reduce delay - look at my answer. If you want to just show/hide tooltip, you can use inside functions (not part of official API) `chart.tooltip.refresh(point)` and `chart.tooltip.hide()`.

Comment: I require a `chart.tooltip.hide()` like api, that does not respect the hideDelay option. I'm working on a plugin, that requires immediate hiding of the tooltip. Is that possible?

Comment: As I said before - you have to set options `hideDelay` in chart options. Then `chart.tooltip.hide()` will respect that value and use it.